# JavaFX 2 TableView header font color

Tags: css, tableview, javafx-2, textcolor

How can I change the text color of the TableView component's header?

I tired this:

```
.table-view .column-header, .table-view .filler {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-border-width: 0, 0;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
}
```

This remove the border, and also change the font size, but not the font color.

Comment: Tried it myself without success. I am pretty sure that your approach is correct, and the color not being set is caused by a bug in JavaFX.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tired it a lot ways and quickly ran out of ideas. :S So maybe it's a bug. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this might work.

```
.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm. So the header texts are inside a label. I dodn't tought about that.

Comment: I would really like to style the header of a *single* column to indicate when something is happening inside of that column that may be out of view and require scrolling.  However, there does not appear to be any way to get to a single column header and apply style.

Answer (score 3):

@David Charles: style classes of the TableColumn also apply to the column header, so to style an individual column header, you can use

```
.table-view .column-header.foo .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

and in Java

```
tableColumn.getStyleClass().add("foo");
```